# How to Customize 403 exception page?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, error-handling, twig

Seriously Symfony documentation is really bad or outdated...

I am trying to customize the Access Denied page.

I followed this "tutorial"

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html

It says

> To override the 404 error template for HTML pages, create a new
>   `error404.html.twig` template located at
>   `templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/:`

But that path doesn't exist at all  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

I keep searching and I found Exception folder on this path

```
vendor\symfony\twig-bundle\Resources\views\Exception
```

I don't even know if it's the correct folder or not.

Anyway, I created `error403.html.twig` inside that folder.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block body %}
        <h1>403 error 123456</h1>
    {% endblock %}
```

Nothing is changed, the error page is still the same!

I keep reading that documentation page manny times and I don't see anything else I should do after that?

What is the right way to Customize those error pages?

Comment: What version of Symfony?

Comment: I am using Symfony version 4.4.5

Comment: Why dont you do what is stated in the docs and put it into `templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/`?
[How to Override any Part of a Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#templates)

Comment: That path doesn't exist on my project ! Should I manually create it ?

Comment: The documentation for that version uses the same path; https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller/error_pages.html - So probably just create it manually

Comment: When I Test it in in development by using  /_error/403 It works fine , But when I access an Access Denied. page (triggered by access_control- { path: ^/braclet, roles: ROLE_ADMIN } In Security.yaml Its the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create this path ( templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/ )
then create the file (error404.html.twig) inside the folder Exception
it will work

[just look this image( you will understand )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJKaA.png)

Comment: How can one change this path?